# In Access VBA, is there a way to count and refer to objects currently open in the main window?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access VBA, is there a centralized way to get a count, and names or references to any objects currently open in the main Access window..?

Access.Application.Screen has the .ActiveDatasheet, .ActiveForm, and .ActiveReport properties, but only one of these will become defined if a valid object becomes active on screen. They do not work with other object types, or non-active objects, meaning those which are further back in the stack of open items.

Access.Application has the .Forms and .Reports properties which do give a count and references of open items, but as above, not for any other object types.

There are the .IsLoaded and .CurrentView properties of the "All-collections", meaning AllForms, AllMacros, etc. These do work, but it seems like looking for a needle in a haystack to loop through all eleven of them to find one or a few items. And if the database has many objects, it might take a while.

Then there's the seemingly antiquated but still effective SysCmd action "acSysCmdGetObjectState". It seems to be the option I seek, especially since it has the nifty ability to work with new/unsaved objects, and also to indicate if they're "dirty", meaning whether they even need to be saved or not. But alas, acSysCmdGetObjectState wants to know the acObjectType and object name, so...back to square one.

So...is there a centralized collection with items currently open on screen, regardless of acObjectType, tab/window position, or new/dirty state..?

Comment: I don't remember if this can loop all objects but check out `containers`, and/or `container.documents`...?

Comment: It seems you're getting into territory where you'll need a WinApi solution. I can try to write one up, but I'm not sure you're actually interested in one. The rest of your research checks out, I can't think of different ways to test if an object is open using just VBA

Comment: @spinjector Can you post sample of these "other objects" ? How are you determining which window is Mani Access window? Can we just walk the list of windows/&/children to get list of all objects?